# Greek letter \xi issue in Matlab eps print out

Tags: matlab

When I plot a figure and type greek letter in the title, it looks like

[image]

However, when I save the figure as EPS output, the eps file looks like
[image]

It's obviously that the Greek letter \xi_p disappears.
Anyone who knows what happened and solutions, please give me a reply.
It would be much grateful.

Best regards,
mike

Comment: have you tried saving the figure in a different format ? and does the "xi" disappear then as well ?

Comment: Hi KiW I tried with PNG, it works fine. But I need EPS file, and if I transfer PNG to EPS, the image loses resolution and looks not so clear.

Comment: Which programm are you using to open the .eps file ? I just created a graph using a Xi and displayed in eps viewer and I dont loose the greek symbol

Comment: I tried with Preview and GSview, they all get wrong.

Comment: can you post how you write your title ?

Comment: You can try with \xi_{p}=1e-4a_{ho} although I am not sure whether it works. I ran your code open it in EPS Viewer and Ghostscript and it I keep the "Xi". Which version of Matlab are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

First I would like to thank *KiW* for the help.
I found a solution that works with my MATLAB 2014b.

---

#### Solution by specifying the interpreter directly in the code

We can set the `interpreter`-property directly to `latex` when calling `xlabel` or `title` as *shamalaima* pointed out in a comment:

```
xlabel('$\xi_{\textrm{p}}$','Interpreter','latex');
title('$\xi_{\textrm{p}}$','Interpreter','latex');
```

---

#### Solution using the property editor

Another way to do it is by using the property editor as follows:

1. After making the figure, click the white arrow and click the title (or label).

   [image]
2. In the Property Editor, change the Interpreter to `latex`.

   [image]
   [image]
3. After this, choose the Axes. We can now find the title editor in the left bottom side. Just write the title as you do in latex.
   Mine would be `$\xi_{_\textrm{p}}=1e$-$4a_{_\textrm{ho}}$` in the font of Times New Roman.
4. It works now in my EPS output.

   [image]
   [image]

Comment: You can do it more simply like [this](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161311)

Comment: Great shamalaima!   we could also use Matlab comand " xlabel('$\xi_{\textrm{p}}$','Interpreter','LaTex') " OR
"title('$\xi_{\textrm{p}}$','Interpreter','LaTex')"

Answer (score 2):

Using EPS Viewer the symbol is not lost. As you can see in the picture that works perfectly fine. I used:

```
plot(x,y)
title('\xi _{P}=1e-4a _{ho}')
```

So I assume it could be a problem of the program you use to open your .EPS file

[image]

Comment: Thanks KiW for your help, I found a way to solve the problem. Will post the answer later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to set the latex interpreter as default:

`set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex')`

but of course it depends case by case.